# Task switcher for linux in multiple monitors?

Tags: linux, multiple-monitors, kde

Anyone know of something like this for linux?

http://www.actualtools.com/multiplemonitors/features/multi_monitor_task_switcher/

Comment: What does it do? Your link just gives me "Error connecting to database."

Comment: Please include full question in the post.

Answer (score 0):

The [xfce4](http://www.xfce.org/) window manager, at least, already does this. Probably most do but I can't verify right now.

Comment: I have used xfce for very years, but after KDE there is no step back (and I refer to monitors not desktops). THX.-

Comment: Up to you. I know you refer to monitors. XFCE has good support for xinerama and multiple monitors. I'm using it now with two monitors so can verify it does work as the link seems to describe.  So the KDE switch doesn't do what you want? Is there a configuration option for that feature?

Comment: Thanks Keith, OK, At least already we know that xfce can.

Answer (score 0):

Deppend what distribution you are using. By default I see that generally have 2 or 4 desktop enables. You can change with shortcuts Alt+Tab or Ctrl+Alt+(Right/Left)Arrow. If you are using a popular distro you should have on the panel something like this (you see here desktops to the left of Trash, in this case):

Or you could add this doing Right click on panel, and choice "Add to Panel" option, and after  Workspace switcher.

If you want to change the number of desktops you can do this with right click on you Workspace switcher/Properties/ and choice the number of desktops that you want. This works on Fedora, Ubuntu and others gnome distros.

If you want more for a gnome based distro you should see [this link](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Customizing_the_Ubuntu_GNOME_Desktop_Panels)

If you have a kde based distro you should see [this link](http://www.mepis.org/docs/en/index.php?title=Enable_Multiple_Desktops_%28workspaces%29_in_KDE/)

And for xfce based distro use Xfce menu > Settings > Workspaces Settings.

For later questions, it is better if you say which distribution or desktop environment you are using

Comment: Thanks, but I clearly say Multiple monitors, not desktops. I ask for a way to have the task switcher in 2 or more monitors at the same time. The link goes to an image that shows that feature in a Windows OS. I would like the same for KDE or linux in general.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Slackware64 with Enlightenment 17, and if I middle click on the desktop anywhere, on any screen, it pops up a list of currently running programs to switch to.

If I just click on the desktop, anywhere, I get the system menu up to run new programs from the menu, in my case the KDE menu.

Admittedly, this is not on both monitors at the same time, but wherever my mouse cursor is, it pops up the menu or list of running programs (list includes all programs running on any monitor) and my visual focus is usually where my mouse pointer is.